# Difference between ​(​3​) and 3 in Clojure

Tags: clojure, code-snippets

​I'm new to clo​j​ure. What is the difference between ​`(​3​)` and just `3`​? If I do `​(3)` ​I get this exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn​​.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `3` is literal number 3.
- `(3)` is a a function application, you are trying to call function `3` with no parameters. (There's no such function and it seems you can't define it.)
- `'(3)` is a list of one item, `3`. It's the same as `(list 3)`, which is a function application.

Here is a repl session:

```
repl=> 3
3
repl=> (3)
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  repl/eval1388 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
repl=> '(3)
(3)
repl=> (list 3)
(3)
repl=> => (defn 3 [] 3)
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj  clojure.core/with-meta (core.clj:211)
```

Answer (score 8):

In lisps parenthesis mean function application, so this:

```
(a b c d)
```

means apply `a` to arguments `b c d`

You're trying to apply `3`, which is not a function, nor can it be converted to one.

Comment: If what you want is a list with 3 as it's only element, you need to quote it: `'(3)`

Answer (score 6):

In Clojure, parentheses mean *function application*. `(3)` is trying to call a function named `3`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

When you start with a Lisp you have to get used to the fact that parenthesis are significative. You can't just add more parenthesis in hope to disambiguate operator priorities – however since everything is in prefix form there's no operator ambiguity.

Once you get used to the fact that all parenethesis matter, try to mentally move the opening one one item to the right, e.g. `(println "hello")`becomes `println("hello")`.

Since the language is very regular it implies that `(3)` should be read as `3()`. `3` is not a function thus you can't call it.

Comment: ​+1 Good answer​, ​but why moving the parenthesis like that is useful?

Comment: The important point is the regularity of the notation (no precedence rules, easier to work with in macros/metaprogramming) rather than the position of the opening paren. At the dawn of times, the parenthsesis wans't planned to stay there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-expression